# Python PHP Like string concatenation

Tags: python

I am developing python application which should work with database. I came along with one problem. In PHP I can make queries with variables directly just by $ sign, but in python I am writing this code:

```
query = "INSERT INTO shops (id, shop_id, shop_url, shop_name, shop_cat, datas)" + "VALUES("+count+", "+str(shop_id)+", "+shop_url+", "+shop_name+", "+shop_cat+", "+pdfs+datas+");"
```

Is there any method doing it like in PHP, I mean doing it inside one string?

Comment: You should really use the DB API and the methods there that do the substitution for you. Building strings this way is fertile ground for SQL injection exploits.

Comment: What you're looking for is called [string interpolation](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+string+interpolation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should **never** concatenate an SQL string like that. You are asking for an SQL injection.

Use the built in escaping in the DB API:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO shops (id, shop_id, shop_url, shop_name, shop_cat, datas) VALUES (%d, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (count, show_id, shop_url, shop_name, shop_cat, pdfs + datas))
```

...and your query will be properly escaped.

In general in Python, you can use "+" to concatenate strings. You can also use printf-like syntax "Hello %s!" % "World" and the newer formatting syntax "Hello {0}".format('World!')

Comment: I am using sqlite3 but it gives error:cursor.execute("INSERT INTO shops (id) VALUES (%d)", (id))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error

Comment: Ahh. Different databases use different placeholders. Sqlite uses '?', so replace %d and %s with ?. http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: Also "(id)" is not the correct way to make a tuple of one element in Python. Use "(id,)". Furthermore "id" is a bad variable name, since it shadows a builtin function called id, but that is more a matter of style.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, but you can use [string formating operations](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations):

```
query = "...VALUES(%d, %d, %s, %s)" % (some_int, some_other_int, some_string, some_other_string)
```

In your case, this is however a **bad idea**. For this kind of things in SQL queries, you should do this instead:

```
query = "INSERT INTO ... VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)"
cursor.execute(query, some_int, some_other_int, some_string, some_other_string)
```

This is the easiest and most effective way to be safe against SQL injections.
This syntax is supported by all major SQL Python modules (at least MySQL, SQLite, PostgreSQL).

More details about this in the [sqlite3 module doc](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute).

Answer (score 0):

How about using formatting:

```
query = (
    "INSERT INTO shops (id, shop_id, shop_url, shop_name, shop_cat, datas)"
    "VALUES(%d, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s%s);" %
    (count, show_id, shop_url, shop_name, shop_cat, pdfs, datas))
```

Or like this:

```
query = (
    "INSERT INTO shops (id, shop_id, shop_url, shop_name, shop_cat, datas)"
    "VALUES(%(count)d, %(show_id)s, %(shop_url)s, %(shop_name)s,"
    " %(shop_cat)s, %(pdfs)s%(datas)s);" % vars())
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't create query by concatenate string like that, use paramterize query like this

```
cursor.execute(""INSERT INTO shops (id, shop_id, shop_url, shop_name, shop_cat, datas) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)", (count, shop_id, shop_url, shop_name, shop_cat, datas))
```

This will save you from a lot of trouble in the long run and it also runs faster. The symbol `?` after `VALUES` can vary between different API

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's a terrible practice to construct SQL queries this way. You should use parametrized queries instead. Now, Python's [DB-API 2.0 (PEP-249)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) defines few param styles:

> paramstyle
>
> ```
>        String constant stating the type of parameter marker
>        formatting expected by the interface. Possible values are
>        [2]:
>
>            'qmark'         Question mark style, 
>                            e.g. '...WHERE name=?'
>            'numeric'       Numeric, positional style, 
>                            e.g. '...WHERE name=:1'
>            'named'         Named style, 
>                            e.g. '...WHERE name=:name'
>            'format'        ANSI C printf format codes, 
>                            e.g. '...WHERE name=%s'
>            'pyformat'      Python extended format codes, 
>                            e.g. '...WHERE name=%(name)s'
> ```

For example for MySQL the default param style is "format" (which is C-style), thus you'd do

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO shops (id, shop_id, shop_url, shop_name, shop_cat, datas) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)" , (count, shop_id, shop_url, shop_name, shop_cat, pdfs+datas)
```

Answer (score 0):

**First of all, *do not* create SQL queries as such. That said, this is how to get named (PHP-style) variable interpolation in Python.**

Use a [string template](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Template). Here is an example:

```
from string import Template

foo = Template('All that $does is $metal.')
bar = foo.substitute(does='glitters', metal='gold')

print(bar) // All that glitters is gold.
```